# How to map `<LocalLeader>s` to send send the selected text to `SlimeRegionSend`?

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, plugin-slime

For python development, I use [slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/) with tmux and the following configuration

```
let g:slime_target = "tmux"
" configuration for vim in a split tmux window with a REPL in the other pane:
let g:slime_default_config = {"socket_name": "default", "target_pane": "{last}"}
```

For R I use [NvimR](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) which has some nice shortcuts based on the `<localleader>` key. I developed some kind of muscle memory to those shortcuts and I sometimes use those shortcuts  inside a python file. I managed to create the following two shortcuts and they work fine, I can send the current line or the current paragraph to tmux:

```
" Similar to NvimR's shortcut send line, but with Slime
autocmd FileType python nmap <LocalLeader>l <Plug>SlimeLineSend
" Shortcut to send the current paragraph with Slime
autocmd FileType python nmap <LocalLeader>p <Plug>SlimeParagraphSend
```

In [vim-slime/plugin/slime.vim](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/blob/main/plugin/slime.vim), I found that there is a `SlimeRegionSend` command. Unfortunately trying to add a shortcut for selected text doesn't work

```
" Similar to NvimR's send selection, but with with slime
autocmd FileType python nmap <LocalLeader>s <Plug>SlimeRegionSend
```

My local leader key is `;` (it's under the middle finger below K on a French AZERTY keyboard). Entering my local leader key `;` followed by s, just replaces the selected text, which is the normal behavior of  the `s` substitute command. I would like instead `;s` to send the current selection to the tmux pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Plug>SlimeRegionSend` appears to work on a visual selection so your mapping should be a visual mode mapping instead of a normal mode mapping:

```
autocmd FileType python xmap <LocalLeader>s <Plug>SlimeRegionSend
```

But there is another issue: mappings defined for a buffer of a given filetype have a tendency to leak to other buffers if you don't force them to be buffer-local. This is done with `:help <buffer>`:

```
autocmd FileType python nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>l <Plug>SlimeLineSend
autocmd FileType python nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>p <Plug>SlimeParagraphSend
autocmd FileType python xmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>s <Plug>SlimeRegionSend
```

Comment: Thank you. Accidentally pressing `s` a second time deletes the selection. It is a little annoying when this happens, so I changed the mapping of `SlimeRegionSend` from `s` to `m`.